# Is it possible for browser to be NOT compatible with JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cross-browser, interpreter

I saw that on jQuery website it says that jQuery is "cross-platform"
But isn't that obvious?
could a browser be not compatible with jQuery?
Given that every browser **is** **essentialy** **an interpreter** for JavaScript,
and Given that jQuery **IS** **JavaScript** code.
Is it possible for me to write a js library that will not be browser compatible?
please help me make sense about this issue
thank you

Comment: why the downvotes? if i m curius about it isn't it possible that others will be too?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but a downvote doesn't necessarily mean your question is not interesting, just that some users feel this violates the site's guideline or has one of the problems highlighted [here](http://idownvotedbecau.se/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible for me to write a js library that will not be browser compatible?

Yes.

In fact one of the huge selling points of jQuery is that it normalizes older browser APIs so that you're actually able to write less code in jQuery, compatible with more browsers, than if you wrote plain javascript.

It's less so the case now with modern browsers

[edit] just as an example, older browsers didn't always implement 'addEventListener' in the same way, particularly Internet Explorer, so jQuery would have normalized that.

Answer (score 2):

[Of course](https://jquery.com/browser-support/).

More broadly, a particular browser may interpret some version of JavaScript which is not the same version jQuery is written against.

Answer (score 1):

Netscape 2.0 probably ...
Else, currents browsers integrates the  V8 javascript engine and are based (on some build) on chromium project (chrome, opera, vivaldi, etc), because that are best.

That is why is useless, on today, to prefix, again, in 2018, the css properties or lost time to try to support  all old browsers < 2016.
Furthermore JQuery is relativly useless in full pack, because ... V8 who implements lots of evolution.
At this day, you can code in full vanilla JS without need jQuery and without difficulties.